# return row header if text present

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

On the sheet Dynamic 3-5 Checklist I want to use the cells in blue (columns B, D, F, etc.) as a reference to look for the text in the range B9:P21 on sheet Dynamic Grade 5, then display the words in column A.

For example, C1 on Dynamic 3-5 Checklist should be populated with the text Typing Program from B12 on Dynamic Grade 5. Also, the text from C1 appeared for any other project the name of that project from the A column would also appear in C1.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lCgHPPXML5Ll9XsrMPXmNnHOEQO0RZP-aWSbMtiCfg4/edit?usp=sharingxxx

Comment: Hi @DavidCantler, It is not as clear as to what you want as output. Can you add a sheet in your sample file that shows the all the expected outputs?

Comment: Was the answer below able to fix your problem @DavidCantler?

Comment: Just responded below. It's super close but not exactly there. Sorry for lack of clarity in post. Hopefully the example helps show the idea.

Comment: You mentioned C1 so I thought it would be there. updated the same sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the formula on your sample sheet (**C1**, **E1**, **G1**, **I1**), please check if those cells show what you wanted to get.

#### Formula:

**C1**:

```
=textjoin(CHAR(10), true, arrayformula(if(isblank(B2:B), "", ifna(vlookup("*"&B2:B&"*", {'Dynamic Grade 5'!B$9:B,'Dynamic Grade 5'!$A$9:$A}, 2, false), ""))))
```

#### Breakdown of the important parts:

1. `{'Dynamic Grade 5'!B$9:B,'Dynamic Grade 5'!$A$9:$A}` - create an array where the 1st column is where the search term is to be searched, and 2nd column is the result we want which is column A
2. `vlookup("*"&B2:B&"*"` - pads the search term with wildcard to capture partial matches (multiple search terms can be found in one cell so normal `vlookup` fails)
3. `textjoin` with `true` - joins all results of `arrayformula` except blank cells

#### Output:

[image: output]

- If you want to get only the unique values, prepend the `arrayformula` with `unique`.

```
=textjoin(CHAR(10), true, unique(arrayformula(if(isblank(B2:B), "", ifna(vlookup("*"&B2:B&"*", {'Dynamic Grade 5'!B$9:B,'Dynamic Grade 5'!$A$9:$A}, 2, false), "")))))
```

[image: unique]

#### Note:

- When copying the formula to other cells in `1:1` range, you only need to update the 1st column of `{}` array since `B2:B` correctly adjusts automatically when copied. See the pattern on the inserted formula on your sheet and you'll get the idea

#### UPDATE:

**C2:**

```
=ifna(join(CHAR(10), index(filter({'Dynamic Grade 5'!B$9:B, 'Dynamic Grade 5'!A$9:A}, 'Dynamic Grade 5'!B$9:B = B2), , 2)), "")
```

Comment: I created an example sheet to show the desired result. On that sheet cell E2 show partially desired results. It should also list the Robot Week and Annual Chromebook Intro. E3 should, for example, list both Social Studies:  Sojourner Truth Unit and ELA: Poetry.

Comment: THen you only need `=arrayformula(if(isblank(D2:D), "", ifna(vlookup("*"&D2:D&"*", {'Dynamic Grade 5'!C$9:C,'Dynamic Grade 5'!$A$9:$A}, 2, false), "")))`. See updated sheet @DavidCantler

Comment: You just need to remove anything outside `arrayformula`, @DavidCantler

Comment: But then the multiple units that meet that standard won't be listed together. The goal is that any unit teachers do that meets a standard shows up together on the Checklist sheet in the cell next to the standard.

Comment: Can you show a sample column that does that? I might have misunderstood what you wanted @DavidCantler

Comment: Done. On the Example sheet, I made column C look like how it should be manually. I'm hoping for that but dynamic.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please see column C. C2 is `=ifna(join(CHAR(10), index(filter({'Dynamic Grade 5'!B$9:B, 'Dynamic Grade 5'!A$9:A}, 'Dynamic Grade 5'!B$9:B = B2), , 2)), "")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238913/discussion-between-nazia-and-david-cantler).

Comment: Hi @DavidCantler, glad it looked great. If this answered your question, please click the accept/upvote button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: I'm noticing that C2 will work only when it detects just the text in B2. I want C2 to populate with information for any project that has the text in B2. Is that possible? Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi @DavidCantler, I'd like to help but I think it would be better if you can post it as a separate issue and have the new post include the complete details instead. We prefer a single post focused on a specific topic. The discussion here is already long and it already starts a little confusing.